# Можно ли проект, созданный в PyCharm, открыть на ПК, на котором не установлен python?

Tags: python, pycharm, проекты

У меня есть код, который нужно запустить на пк без python. Я понял, что компиляция в ексешник не поможет (да и нервы трепать я не собираюсь), вот хотелось бы узнать.

Comment: Нельзя. Минус интерпретируемых языков в том, что для запуска нужно обязательно иметь интерпретатор.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Go - компилируемый язык. В Python можно упаковать код, все необходимые для него библиотеки и сам интерпретатор в самораспаковываемый архив, который будет прикидываться исполняемым файлов, но это жуткий костыль с кучей недостатков.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, да понятно что непонятно без виртуального окружения не понятно как быть с быть с зависимостями

Comment: Куче людей помогло, а вам нет? :) да и нервы может и не будете трепать, например самый простой пример сборки в exe `pyinstaller --onefile main.py`: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/455d445299f12a2653d725e0383b5926c3c2c1dc/build_exe/pyinstaller_example/console/hello_world/build_exe.bat Да и вы всегда можете со своей программой таскать папку питона, а запускать скрипт (.py / .pyw) через батник (.bat / .cmd) (при желании к этому батнику сделать ярлык с нужной иконкой)

Comment: gil9red, а он откроется, если установлена библиотека tkinter?